Webpack and React project page is coming blank on Vercel
My application is working fine on the localhost, and build is working fine on the localhost. In the local when I run command "npx serve" in the build folder, it's working fine.
But when I deploy my app to Vercel, the blank page is coming.
Vercel page output in the browser.
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WebPack React</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root">xyz</div>
</body></html>

webpack.common.js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './src/index.tsx'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './build'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
        mainFields: ['source', 'module', 'main'],
        modules: [path.resolve('node_modules')],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(?:js|ts|tsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(?:css|scss)$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf|svg|)$/,
                type: 'asset/inline', // note: you can also use asset/resource for svgs, but it is best when you have large svgs, so it enables caching and also outputs a smaller js bundle size but it increases the number of network request as svgs are emitted as separate files. But asset/inline is best for small svgs. svgs are embedded into js bundles as data urls so it increases bundle size, but reduces http requests.
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './public/index.html'),
            showErrors: true,
        }),
        new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin(),
    ],
    stats: 'error-only',
}

webpack.prod.js
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common');

const prodConfig = {
    mode: 'production',
    devtool: 'source-map',
}
module.exports = merge(commonConfig, prodConfig);

package.json file is
{
  "name": "remoteapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --config webpack/webpack.dev.js",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.prod.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.25.2",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-class-properties": "^7.25.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.25.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.25.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.24.7",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.24.7",
    "@types/node": "^22.5.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.4",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^9.0.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.6.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.9.1",
    "sass": "^1.77.8",
    "sass-loader": "^16.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.5.4",
    "webpack": "^5.94.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^5.0.4",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^6.0.1"
  }
}


